# I am trying to disable userInteraction on a tableview from another view in the VC, but it wont let me call the function

Tags: swift, uitableview, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to follow MVC, which has all the logic for a view in its own file, rather than the view controller. What I am trying to do right now is enlarge a photo when you tap it, and then disable interaction with the tableview that it is now in front of (tapping the enlarged image just taps the tableview beneath it instead...).

Here is kind of what I have tried:

```
class TripsVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

static var imageCache:NSCache<NSString, NSData> = NSCache()

func disable() {
    tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
}
```

and then

class profileView: ShadowedView {

```
@IBOutlet var profilePictureView:UIImageView!

var aviFullscreen = false
var initalAviRect:CGRect!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    initalAviRect = profilePictureView.frame

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.showPhoto(_sender:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

    profilePictureView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}


func showPhoto(_sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    superview?.bringSubview(toFront: profilePictureView)
    switch aviFullscreen {
    case false:
        aviFullscreen = true
        TripsVC.disable() //Issue Here -----------------------
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.profilePictureView.frame = CGRect(x: (self?.superview?.frame.width)! * 0.125, y: 140, width: (self?.superview?.frame.width)! * 0.75, height: (self?.superview?.frame.width)! * 0.75)
            }, completion: nil)
    default:
        aviFullscreen = false
        TripsVC.enable() // Issue here---------------------
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.profilePictureView.frame = (self?.initalAviRect)!
            }, completion: nil)
    }

}

}
```

When I try to call the enable/disable functions in my profileView, it wont let me. It gives the error:

"Instance member "disable" cannot be used on type "TripsVC""

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling those methods on the `TripsVC` instance, you are trying to call it directly on the type (which won't work).

You need to add a way to get access to the VC object that you want to enable/disable.

The normal way is to:

1. define a protocol with the disable/enable functions
2. add a var to this class of the type of the protocol
3. Implement the protocol in the VC
4. Set the protocol var of this class to the VC
5. call enable/disable through that var

So,

1:

```
protocol Enableable {
    func enable()
    func disable()
}
```

2:

```
var outerGUI: Enableable? = nil
```

3:

```
class TripsVC: UIViewController, Enableable // and whatever else you need
```

4:  In TripsVC somewhere

```
 yourView.outerGUI = self
```

5:  In the class you are showing

```
 outerGUI?.enable() // or disable
```

You often see this called a delegate pattern or something like that.